# Percentage of proximity to cluster in kmeans

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, k-means

I am trying to clustering in python.

This is my script as follows:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2
from collections import Counter

def dist(a,b): return np.linalg.norm(a-b)

X = scipy.randn(100, 2)

k=int(raw_input("Give value of k: "))

pts = 100*np.random.random((12,2))
centroids, assigned_clusters = kmeans2(X, k)
for pt in pts:
    #print tuple(pt)
    distperxy=dict()
    i=1
    for cent in centroids:
        distperxy[i]=(float(dist(pt,list(cent))))
        i+=1
    mnmm=min(distperxy.iterkeys(), key=(lambda key: distperxy[key]))
    tot = sum(distperxy.values())
    perc=distperxy[mnmm]/tot
    print mnmm,perc
```

Basically I am trying to determine the nearest cluster for each point and the percentage of proximity to that cluster. So for example if point A is near to centroid1 in k-means where k=3. Would the percentage calculation be as described in the code above,i.e, dividing the distance to the closest cluster by sum of distances to clusters?

Comment: You would do well to precisely define "percentage of proximity". It seems to me that you want some kind of estimate of the certainty that tells you how certain you are that a point is in cluster A vs cluster B. Points right on the boundary between cluster A and cluster B should have equal certainty of being in either. If you want to think of ways of calculating this, you should consult some statistics textbooks or invent your own. Be careful to define your invented metric for anyone you present it to, because "percent of proximity" is not a standard metric.

Comment: As a suggestion, for each point a and cluster c in set of clusters C, compute 1/r or 1/r^2, where r is the distance between point a and the centroid of cluster c, put them all in an array together, and divide by the sum of the array. This will give you an array of "percentages of proximity". Alternatively, you can use any decreasing function of r, but again, you ought to define your terms for anyone consuming the results.